# Can I mark a method as deprecated for Kotlin callers, but not for Java callers?

Tags: java, kotlin

I want to extend an API in a way that's useful for Kotlin callers, but not Java callers. Therefore I'd like to encourage Kotlin users to switch to a new method, without bothering Java users. We have a large codebase that's a mix of Java and Kotlin, and won't be 100% Kotlin any time soon.

Is there a way to add a `@Deprecate` tag or similar that only shows up in Kotlin, not Java?

If you're interested in the specific details, we have a `Log` interface that takes a formatted string, something like this:

`Log.get().info("Log message with some $expensive $things to $format")`

That string is created on every call, even if logging is disabled. Fixing the logger API to take the format string and arguments separately would be a big and disruptive change. However, Kotlin's nullable types could give us a very cheap solution:

`Log.getNullable()?.info("This $expensive $format should be skipped if there's no logger")`

Just a case of replacing `get().` with `getNullable()?.` in all the Kotlin code. But I wouldn't want to use `getNullable()` in Java code because there's a risk of `NullPointerException`. So the old `Log.get` method should ideally be deprecated in Kotlin, but not in Java.

Comment: what does `Log.get()` return and how could this be null? Are you making it nullable only to prevent something from happening in the calling class? (that seems a bit odd)

Comment: `Log.get()` returns a `Logger` object (but note, not a standard `java.util.logging.Logger` for legacy reasons). It always returns a valid `Logger` but in certain build configurations the log messages will just be thrown away, so the time spent formatting the string is wasted. This mostly quite cheap but not always.

So yes, I want to return null to stop the caller formatting the string.

Comment: could you please show how the current `Log` is implemented? or what it is (object? companion?)? also: how are the `getNullable` defined now?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a class `Log` whose methods are defined in the `companion object`, e.g.:

```
class Log {
  companion object {
    @JvmStatic
    fun get() : String = TODO()
    @JvmStatic
    fun getNullable() : String? = TODO()
  }
}
```

What about just removing the `@JvmStatic`? or creating an extension function instead?

```
fun Log.Companion.getNullable() : String? = TODO()
class Log {
  companion object {
    @JvmStatic
    fun get() : String = TODO()
  }
}
```

Extension functions are usually not that easily accessible in Java as they are in Kotlin. Both, removing `@JvmStatic` or the extension function would require the following in the Java code: `Log.Companion.getNullable` instead of `Log.getNullable`... Maybe that's also ok for you instead of deprecating it.

Even if my guess is off, an extension function may suit your needs here.

Regarding deprecating a method only for Kotlin... I don't think that works, but here is another workaround for that. Just rename the method and use `@JvmName("get")` on the method, e.g.:

```
@JvmStatic
@JvmName("get")
fun dont_ever_use_this_method_again_in_Kotlin() : String = TODO()
```

That will allow `Log.get` from Java but doesn't from Kotlin. And I think we can agree that no one will call `Log.dont_ever_use_this_method_again_in_Kotlin` in Kotlin, right?

Comment: funny enough... just played around by deprecating the companion object... that didn't give me any error in Java, but it showed the deprecation on the Kotlin side :-)

Comment: Yep, I definitely want to hide the new method from Java callers and this is a good way to do it. But my question is how to deprecate/hide the old method for Kotlin callers.

Comment: Wow, deprecating the companion object! That's a nifty idea, I'll give it a try!

Comment: that rather smells like a bug to me... when consulting the javadoc, the deprecation is shown... :-/

Comment: ok... have something for you to never call a method in Kotlin again ;-) `@JvmName` may do the trick... (it's just a workaround... but that's `getNullable()?` to, right? ;-) )

Comment: OK, deprecating the companion object gets me part way because the deprecation shows up in Kotlin but not in Java. However, it effectively deprecates *all* the static methods in `Log` and I don't see any way to add a new non-deprecated one (extension methods show up as deprecated too).

Comment: I think that's probably a bug... at least I would have expected the `Companion` to be deprecated in Java as well...

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts for this

- Hide a method from Kotlin Caller
- Hide a method from Java Caller

For hiding a method from Java Caller, `@JvmSynthetic` can be used; more on it [here](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-jvm-synthetic/).
For hiding a method from Kotlin Caller I could not find a direct way of doing it but as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53083112/11801106) you can use `@JvmName` to provide a good name for the method and add a deprecation message in the actual `fun` name

So now the Class will look like

```kotlin
class Log {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        @JvmName("get")
        fun dont_dare_using_this_from_kotlin_use_getNullable_instead(): String = TODO()

        @JvmSynthetic
        fun getNullable(): String = TODO()
    }
}
```